# Routes in Play Framework

Tags: playframework

Updating the routes file in the conf directory of my Play application does not seem to be reflecting.

```
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
GET     /channel                    controllers.Application.createMember()


# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

When I make a request to my server at localhost:9000/channel it says action not found. My play application currently resides inside Eclipse work space.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just guessing that you added the route and was trying to call in the `production mode` which **does not** use hot reload feature.

Restart your application and check again.

Use `play run` command instead of `play start` to stay in the `development mode` (which reflects code changes without redeployment). It will recompile changed classes after next browser request.

If you'll use `play ~run` it will recompile changed classes right after saving them (even before next request).